# Kohana 3.3 Auth module fails with remember flag and creating user token

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-auth

I am attempting to log in users with:

`$login = Auth::instance()->login($this->request->post('username'), $this->request->post('password'), TRUE);`

However it fails when trying to set the autologin cookie, with `ErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object` when it gets to:

```
// Token data
$data = array(
    'user_id'    => $user->pk(),
    'expires'    => time() + $this->_config['lifetime'],
    'user_agent' => sha1(Request::$user_agent),
);

// Create a new autologin token
$token = ORM::factory('User_Token')
            ->values($data)
            ->create();

// var_dump($token); // null

// Set the autologin cookie
Cookie::set('authautologin', $token->token, $this->_config['lifetime']);
```

If I `var_dump($token)` it says it is `null`. I have checked the database and it appears to be added correctly. My config has `driver => 'ORM'`. Logging in works if the remember me flag is set to FALSE. Why is $token not an object? Is there something I have missed?

Comment: @ITroubs updated the question with `$data`

Comment: The notice is at what exact line?

Comment: @ITroubs at `Cookie::set('authautologin', $token->token, $this->_config['lifetime']);` It seems `$token->token` is failing.

Comment: well if var_dump($token); returns null then $token->token won't be possible.... so there was something wrong with your ORM mapping

Comment: try to split the creation of your token and to var_dump it after every function call. maybe that will clear where the problem comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caused the error by overriding the `create()` method in `class ORM_Base extends Kohana_ORM` which then called the `parent::create()` but directed the user_token to the wrong create(). Fixed by removing the create() I added.